# My bootstrap dropdown is working but the starting <li> in the nav is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

https://www.marlincash.com/  is the site I am working on.
I've created a bootstrap drop down list for "APPLY NOW" in the main nav. The drop down works fine, but now the "APPLY NOW" link is dead.    This is what I've got:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>car-title-loan-apply-now" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Apply Now</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu-left dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="sub-list" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>car-title-loan-apply-now">Car Title Loans</a></li>
    <li><a class="sub-list" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>boat-title-loan-apply-now">Boat Title Loans</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

All the classes come directly from Bootstrap so their css is the usual. 
Any help you could offer would be amazing! Thank you.

Comment: I think it's the way i should work... Perhaps you want to add a 1st item with the link

Comment: It seems to be working just fine, unless you want the user to go straight to the thank you page and bypass the application.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing the issue by adding the class "disabled" to the head li tag.